# Jekyll dates localization

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to make blog. I use jekyll and poole framework.
And I want to localize my posts' dates.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  * {{ post.date | date_to_string }} &raquo; [ {{ post.title }} ]({{ post.url }})
{% endfor %}
```

And here is how I try to make localization:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  * {% assign m = page.date | date: "%-m" %}
  {{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}
    {% case m %}
      {% when '1' %}Января
      {% when '2' %}Февраля
      {% when '3' %}Марта
      {% when '4' %}Апреля
      {% when '5' %}Мая
      {% when '6' %}Июня
      {% when '7' %}Июля
      {% when '8' %}Августа
      {% when '9' %}Сентября
      {% when '10' %}Октября
      {% when '11' %}Ноября
      {% when '12' %}Декабря
    {% endcase %}
    {{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}
    &raquo; [ {{ post.title }} ]({{ post.url }})
{% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to make it according to http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples (Outside U.S. Style with Non-English Full Month Name). But it does not work: dates just does not appear. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `page.date`. It should be `post.date`.